# Ruby: Forcing an Integer (Fixnum/Bignum) over Boolean

Tags: ruby, integer, boolean

I have an integer that is initially 0 and, after calculations, often ends up between 0 - 99. The problem is that since early on in the game, it calculates out to 0 or 1 often, it gets assigned as a TrueClass or FalseClass instead of a numerical value, which messes up a future x > 0 comparison. Is there a built-in Ruby way to force the variable into being a Fixnum/Integer type or will I have to monkeypatch it?

Here is the code it applies to:

## Step 10: Compute the Target's Magic Defense Multiplier

```
mdef_multi = self.mdef_multi

# Step 11: Modify the Magic Defense Multiplier
# If Toad
mdef_multi = 0 if user.states.include?(11)
# If Charging
mdef_multi = 0 if user.states.include?(30)
# If cast on self or PC onto PC
# 0 if PC targetting PC
mdef_multi = self.is_a?(Game_Actor) and user.is_a?(Game_Actor) ? 0 : mdef_multi
# 99 MDef Multi if max MDef
mdef_multi = self.is_a?(Game_Enemy) and mdef == 255 ? 99 : mdef_multi
# If Solo Multiplier is enabled
mdef_multi = obj.element_set.include?(26) ? 1 : mdef_multi

# Step 12: Modify the Spell Multiplier
hits = 0, missed = 0, evaded = 0
while spl_multi > 0
  spl_multi -= 1
  if rand(99) <= hit
    if mdef_multi > 0
```

The last line is where I run into the variable-type issue. 
It's technically RGSS2 from RPG Maker VX. And please excuse
my horrid commenting and coding style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Ruby doesn't auto-convert things, so your integer isn't getting converted to a boolean because it's 0 or 1.

Instead, what's happening is the line

```
mdef_multi = self.is_a?(Game_Actor) and user.is_a?(Game_Actor) ? 0 : mdef_multi
```

is being parsed as

```
( mdef_multi = self.is_a?(Game_Actor) ) and user.is_a?(Game_Actor) ? 0 : mdef_multi
```

because of the way `and` works.  Basically `=` has higher precendence than `and`, so the variable is only being set to the result before the `and`, which is a `true`/`false` value.  `&&` has a higher precedence than `=` though, so using `&&` here should work.  For this reason, some Ruby programmers recommend only using `&&`, never `and`. See http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/08/ruby-operator-precedence-of-and-which.html for more explanation.

If you use `&&` instead of `and` on this line and the next one, it should fix the problem.